# How to address large data?

Tags: largedatavolumes, account-management

AtaHi guys：

i have a things about salesforce account tables. In my scenario, I have more than 600000 record in my account table. And currently, we want to admin all account territory. So, I want to find out a best ways how to address large data? If I write a new vf page,how to load large data?

Comment: Address large data how? What operations are you trying to perform? Do they need to affect every record or just smaller subsets? Mohith provided you with some good general guidelines for Visualforce, but if you need something more specific you'll need to add details to your question.

Comment: @MikeChale  salesforce.com not provide friendly web page to managing Account and User territory. So, my company want to developer a new web page to my end user and provide a function that would be effect be managing change Account and User territory. but, In my scenario, i have very large data in Account table(>600000 record).  So, my question is , how to address large data load? Or, if i use vf page, how to load large data?

Answer (score 3):

The three major challenges are 1)One can query only 50000 rows in a context 2)One can do DML on 10k rows 3)The view state limit

The following have helped me

1)Use read only annotaion and attribute that can increase number of rows if you want data only for view purpose

2)Use transient keyword to reduce view state

3)Raise a case and get fields indexed to avoid time out issues while apex executes soql

4)Initially display less no of records(most recent or those tagged as important by client) and provide a search box so that you will be able to filter data based on search parameters entered by user.Also try to display message to user to go for more filtering if your query returns huge no of rows. (say 10k at which view state limit exceeds)

5)Make use of FOR SOQL to avoid heap size blowing up.

6)Make use of StandardSet controller for pagination as this has Querylocator to help you in pagination